# Building a predictive model for the Return on Investment (RoI)

Tags: regression, time-series, econometrics, dependent-variable

I am working at a company that invests in ads for apps at different stores. I have a dataset containing the columns `date`, `app`, `investment`, `revenue`, `visualizations` and some others. So for a given date and a given app, I know how much money was spent that day (`investment`), and how much money was generated by that app that day (`revenue`). I also know how many peple viewed the add (`visualizations`). The number of observations (this is, the number of days) available for each app depends. For one app I have information for the last year, but maybe for another app in which the investment started recently I only have information for the last 15 days.

With this information I computed the Return On Investment (basically is `(revenue - investment)/investment`). I think this metric only makes sense when I look to the aggregated data, meaning that, for a certain day, I use the information regarding to the sum of that day and all days before that one.

With all this said, what I want is to build a predictive model that for a specific app can give an estimation of the RoI for next week. I am not sure on how to do this. What troubles me is that:

1. I considered using some time series methodology, but there is no stationality on the data, nor a clear trend. The revenue depends largely on the investment so if the investment increases, the revenue will increase. But it will not increase the same way for all the apps.
2. I considered using something like a linear regression model between the roi for one day, and the investment, revenue and visualizations for previous week. But what worries me here is that by considering the aggregated data for each day, my observations are not independent at all.
3. My boss is saying that I should not work with the total aggregation of the data, but that I should consider 1-month aggregation, meaning that for each day I take the sum of the previous month. But I think this does not make any sense. If there is a large investment and the revenue takes, say, two months, to be reflected by this investment, a 1-month aggregation will not reflect this.
4. Also, the roi is a value bounded between -1 and infinity. So I am not sure if it makes sense at all to try and use regression techniques here.

I am lost on how to face this project and any ideas are more than welcomed.

Comment: This is a typical problem in this space, so it must have been previously discussed somewhere (vaguely remember a podcast). Historic investment matters (but how much so & in what form - e.g. declining with time, how fast etc.?). Other topics: some apps have less potential (e.g. just bad/worse than competiton, targeted at a narrow audience...) than others & no ads change that. It's a tricky causal inference/modeling Q where you need to attribute outcomes to different causes (in the absence of randomized A/B tests, I guess).Could also model something else e.g. apps sold & calculate ROI from that.

Answer (score 6):

you just have to start!

see https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/guides/rules-of-ml

decide on your criterion (eg error in predicted revenue^2?)

[I would do revenue as the criterion rather than ROI because you don't care about amazing roi on a minuscule investment - you care about your overall revenue]

create a benchmark (time series crossvalidation of next week given previous data)

what's the simplest model you can come up with?

eg roi next week = roi last week/month/all time.

what gives the best results?

iterate.

personally I would use logs of your data, eg

$\log(\text{revenue}) = \log(\text{investment}) + \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 \log (\text{revenue (week-1)}) - \beta_1 \log(\text{investment(week -1)}) + \dots \alpha_n \log (\text{revenue (week-n)}) - \beta_n \log(\text{investment(week -n)})$

ie

$$\text{revenue} = \text{investment} \exp(\alpha_0) * \frac{\prod_i(\text{revenue}^{\alpha_i})}{\prod_j(\text{investment}^{\beta_j})}$$

the point is that your regression could chose some weighted (geometric) average of the previous weeks' ROI. (not exactly correct.. will revisit)

Answer (score 2):

i think this is pretty much an univariate mix marketing modelling problem, you have the investment on the app on the x axis , and the return on the y axis. you can take a look at how these problems are usually approached as they also measure how much each channel returns on investment both in the manner of how much does 1 dolar investment relates to sales, and how many people can this channel actually reach before saturation

Comment: OP you could look at eg https://facebookexperimental.github.io/Robyn/docs/features/ eg ad_stock and saturation